# Нужна Библиотека для пepeфpaзиpoвки текста на русском

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск-библиотек, библиотека

Нужна Библиотека для пepeфpaзиpoвки текста на ***русском***. Можете подсказать название библиотеки которая может выполнять данную функцию, если такие есть конечно.

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под перефразировкой? Замена слов на синонимы? Замена предложений на другие с таким же смыслом?

Comment: Передать предложение в несколько изменённом виде, но с таким же смыслом (Замена слов на синонимы, изменение структуры предложения, сокращение предложения)

Comment: Ну на синонимы наверное не сложно будет. Готовое так навскидку не знаю, но придумать что-то можно, наверное. А что по сути то - это копирайтинг? ))

Comment: Нет немного для других целей